# basic authentication in IIS with basichttpBinding WCF issue

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, basic-authentication

I have just put my webservice onto IIS 7 and I need to use basic authentication, I have set this up in IIS 7 by enabling it, however I am getting the common error:

> the http request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'basic' the authentcation header received from the server was 'basic
>   realm' = "server address"

In my client I am using

```
binding.Security.Mode = ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Basic
```

With the same settings in the service

```
 <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="binding1">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
     /binding>
 </basicHttpBinding>
```

I see that a lot of solutions to this is to use a different security mode like `transport` which uses HTTPS and a certificate instead of HTTP. I dont want this, so is there anyway of solving this without HTTPS?

Thanks

Comment: But you know that using basic authentication over HTTP means that you're risking your credentials being sniffed, right? You may as well not bother with authentication at all.

Comment: yeah I know, its just for proof of concept really, this wont be used in a live environment

Comment: OK, that feels a bit better :-). To get an answer, you will need to give a bit more info. Where do you get the error?

Comment: Np, its when I go and call a method from the service, so `cilent.getdata()`

Comment: Try `<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">`.

Comment: Doesnt that use https?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think you can use it with both HTTP and HTTPS. Try it and let me know.

Comment: The new error message is now - The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'. Parameter name: via

Comment: Yeah, it needs `<message>`. OK, go back to your original `TransportCredentialOnly` and try adding `realm="server address"` to your `<transport .../>`. Of course the value of the realm needs to match the one you get in the error message that posted at the top of your question.

Comment: does that realm addition just need to go into the service?

Comment: You're right. You probably also need to set the `binding.Security.Transport.Realm`